# rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking (statd unrecognized service)

Tags: centos, mount, nfs

I'm attempting to mount a nfs share (fstab entry below)

```
example.com:/sharefolder            /mnt/localmount           nfs     defaults
```

The following error is returned:

```
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

Checked the basics:

```
[acoder@box iptables]# service rpcbind status
rpcbind (pid  3435) is running...

[acoder@box iptables]# service nfslock status
rpc.statd (pid  1666) is running...

[acoder@box iptables]# service statd status
statd: unrecognized service

[acoder@box ~]# yum provides rpc.statd
1:nfs-utils-1.2.3-70.el6.x86_64 : NFS utilities and supporting clients and daemons for the kernel NFS server
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: rpc.statd
```

Why isn't statd recognized as a service as it appears to be installed?

Edit, here's what's in /var/log/messages

```
Jun 29 21:11:03 box rpc.statd[5966]: Version 1.2.3 starting
Jun 29 21:11:03 box rpc.statd[5966]: Flags: TI-RPC 
Jun 29 21:11:03 box rpc.statd[5966]: Failed to create listener xprt (statd, 1, udp6)
Jun 29 21:11:03 box rpc.statd[5966]: Failed to create listener xprt (statd, 1, tcp6)
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a couple years and I don't recall how I worked around this.  I believe we since upgraded this box to EL7 though.

Comment: This is NFSv3, NFSv4 has locking built-in. My usual start is `mount -v <nfs>:<export>` and `rpcinfo -p <host>`.